# How to calculate running time of algorithm

Tags: arrays, performance, algorithm, time-complexity

I am trying to improve my knowledge in Algorithms and I was wondering if someone can give me a good explanation on how to easily calculate running time.

```
boolean hasDuplicate(int[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) {
                return true;
            }
       }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So it says:
This  array  takes  O(n<sup>2</sup>)  running  time  because  each  element  has  to  be compared  with  n  elements (where  n  is  the  length  of  the  array).   Therefore, if  we  double  the  input size, we  quadruple  the running  time.

Question:

Let's say the array was [1,2,3] and if we double it [1,2,3,4,5,6], how does that take quadruple?  Shouldn't that be double the running time too?

Comment: Work through this by hand noting each individual operation that the code undertakes.  You'll get the picture.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on the CS Stack Exchange.

Comment: Do you understand what `n` is in `O(n^2)`?  It's the input, so no matter the input size, the big-O will be `O(n^2)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement executes `array.length * array.length` times. That's `O(N^2)` if `N` denotes the array length.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to think about this - your for loop iterates over all possible pairs of indices into the array (do you see why?)

Let's suppose you have an array of length n. There are n<sup>2</sup> possible pairs of indices into that array (do you see why?). If you double the size of the array to 2n, then the number of possible pairs of indices is (2n)<sup>2</sup> = 4n<sup>2</sup>. Notice that this is four times the original number, meaning that there are four times more pairs to consider. Therefore, since the runtime of your code is proportional to the number of pairs of indices in the array, the runtime should go up by a factor of four.

More generally, any quadratic-time algorithm should take roughly four times as long to finish when you double the size of the input.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The loops iterate over the array `n` number of times. Say, consider the first loop :

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) {
            return true;
        }
   }
}
```

The variable `i` will have values from `0` to `n-1`. `n` denotes the length of the array in your case.

For each value of `i`, the variable `j` will have values from `0` to `n-1`.

Say, `n = 5`. Then

```
i = 0  j <-- 0,1,2,3,4
i = 1  j <-- 0,1,2,3,4
i = 2  j <-- 0,1,2,3,4
i = 3  j <-- 0,1,2,3,4
i = 4  j <-- 0,1,2,3,4
```

You can see that the index changes `5 x 5 = 25 times`. This is equal to `n-squared times`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I learned it is this: as an experiment, change the program to not use comparisons directly. Instead, write a function `compareTo` that does the comparison, but also tracks how many comparisons have been done. Then do the following:

1. Run the sort with an O(n^2) algorithm and K, 2K, 3K, 4K elements. Log the number of elements sorted and the number of comparisons for each run.
2. Repeat 1, but with an O(n log n) sort.
3. Graph the results

You should see that, indeed, you get a quadratic curve for the first, and a curve that looks between a line and a quadratic for the second.

Answer (score 0):

Given your example, for [1,2,3] input

```
        if (array[i] == array[j] && i != j) {
            return true;
        }
```

this part of the code is executed 3*3=9 times, but when the input is [1,2,3,4,5,6] this part of the code is executed 6*6=36 times. This is how runtime is quadrupled (36/9=4).

In general, when the amount of elements in the input is N, this if statement is executed N*N times, which makes the runtime O(N^2).